# R não está reconhecendo os separadores do arquivo csv

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, csv

Tenho alguns arquivos para trabalhar no R, com dados em números decimais. Os arquivos que estão com os separadores como `;` estão sendo lidos corretamente, mas um deles está com `,` como limite entre as células. Não sei como corrigir esse problema no Linux Ubuntu. Existe algum outro jeito que não seja nas configurações regionais para que o arquivo fique no formato correto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na função `read.csv` existe as opções de separador. No caso do arquivo com `,` especifique dentro da função

```
dados <- read.csv("arquivo.csv", sep = ",")
```

Comment: Mesmo tendo algumas vírgulas nos meus dados como casa decimal, isso não desconfiguração tudo? Não faria confusão?

Comment: como esse é o caso, você não deve nem conseguir fazer a leitura do arquivo, provavelmente vai dar um erro do tipo: `more columns than column names`. Nesse caso, eu te sugiro dar uma olhada na função `read.fwf` onde vai especificar o comprimento de cada coluna

Comment: Entendi! Vou fazer isso! Muito obrigada